# Need to do a conditionnal LIKE request

Tags: sql, sql-like

Here I am struggling with SQL

I made a search bar that can match with three different rows in sql.
Problem, one of these rows isn't in the same table as the two others.

Here is an example

```
 TABLE 1 : topics
 id  ||  name        ||  category || id_merchant
 1   ||  football    ||  Sports   || 1
 2   ||  marmalade   ||  cooking  || 2
 3   ||  Hitchcock   ||  cinema   || 3

 TABLE 2 : merchant
 id || merchant
 1  || NIKE
 2  || Cooking Corp
 3  || GoodFilms Corp
```

**PROBLEM with this request (when I'm searching for "Corp" keyword) :**

```
SELECT T.name, T.category, M.merchant 
FROM topics AS T, 
     merchant AS M 
WHERE T.name LIKE '%Corp%' 
   OR T.category LIKE '%Corp%' 
   OR M.merchant LIKE '%Corp%' 
  AND T.id_merchant = M.id
```

It returns all the merchant that "Corp" in there names, but **I only want to retrieve a topic that have a merchant matching with "Corp"**

Then I tried this :

```
SELECT T.name, T.category, M.merchant 
FROM topics AS T, 
     merchant AS M 
WHERE T.name LIKE '%Corp%' 
   OR T.category LIKE '%Corp%' 
   OR (SELECT M.merchant WHERE M.id = T.id_merchant) LIKE '%Corp%' 
  AND T.id_merchant = M.id
```

But it returns a syntax error.

Hope I was clear enough.

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the topics where the merchant's name has 'Corp' in it.
Then that would be the only criteria I guess?

```
SELECT T.name, T.category, M.merchant 
FROM topics AS T
INNER JOIN merchant AS M ON (M.id = T.id_merchant)
WHERE M.merchant LIKE '%Corp%'
```

Note that the JOIN syntax is used to increase readability.

Btw, I notice you like using OR's. 
So an advice, it's best to use parentheses when using both OR's and AND's. 
Because AND's are evaluated before OR's. 
So `m OR n AND x OR y` is evaluated as `m OR (n AND x) OR y`.

So with the other OR's included:

```
SELECT T.name, T.category, M.merchant 
FROM topics AS T
LEFT JOIN merchant AS M ON (M.id = T.id_merchant)
WHERE (
   M.merchant LIKE '%Corp%' OR 
   T.name LIKE '%Corp%' OR 
   T.category LIKE '%Corp%'
)
```

*(not really needed for the sample data)*
*(notice that the LEFT JOIN was used this time.  That's just to catch also the topics that don't even have a merchant)*

Comment: No, sorry if I wasn't clear but the keyword can match with name, category and merchant, but it was the INNER JOIN was missing in my request ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you want to understand the different joins, [this old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/) has been popular. Although, it's mostly just INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN that are used the most.